# /etc/sudoers file problem understanding

Tags: sudo, configuration, users, remote-access, visudo

According to the documentation, modifications of this file may enables local users to execute sudo commands on remote machines:

```
user1    192.168.1.14=(user2:group1) ALL
```

According to what I read, this entry enables user1 to execute all commands on the host with the IP 192.168.1.14. How can this be possible?

I also have problems understanding what does running commands as different users means?

Answer (score 1):

You have misread the documentation. Given the spec:

```
user host = (target_user:target_group) command
```

in the `sudoers` of a system with hostname/IP `host`, `user` can execute `command` as `target_user`/`target:group`. If the system doesn't have hostname/IP `host`, this rule doesn't apply. Only the current system's hostname/IP is ever checked. It does not apply to remote systems. Think of this as an administrative tool. A system administrator, with care, can use the same `sudoers` file on all systems in the network, and use the `host` specification to distribute privileges accordingly.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but I will have to ask one more question. Correct me if I got you wrong. It seems to me that the user specified in the user field will have to have a local account on the target machine in order to execute the sudo command with the specified permission?

Comment: @majestik33 not a local account, exactly. Any account will do. LDAP accounts, for example, are enough if the system allows login via LDAP.